# Making a table in Latex with both single and multicolumn table headers

Tags: tables, formatting

I am very new to using Latex and only know the basics when it comes to creating tables. I need to create a table that has 5 columns and header made from 2 rows.

The first column in the header should be the same size as the rest of the first column.

The second and third rows of the header should share the 1st column header title, with two categories making up the second row of the header that lines up with the rest of the second and third columns.

I would then repeat the process above for the fourth and fifth columns.

I have provided a picture of what my table looks like in word for reference. Is this possible to do in LaTeX? In the attached picture, I have drawn red lines outlining where the different parts of the header and columns should be.

Thanks in advance[image: Table from word]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you looked into the `\multicolumn` macro?

Comment: I have a little, but a lot of it is too advanced for me. Do you think this will work in this case where I have multicolumns and single columns?

Comment: That's the intention of `\multicolumn`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

- `\multicolumn{2}{c}{Text}` to have a cell with content `Text`, aligned as `c` (you could also add vertical lines here), spanning `2` columns. This can be used for single columns, or some or all columns in a row.
- `\multirow{2}{*}{Text}` to have a cell with content `Text` spanning `2` rows.

Note: Using `multicolumn` you just skip the merged cells, while for `multirow` you still type the merged cells but leave them empty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{$AR$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Re=110$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Re=1400$} \\
    & 1\textsuperscript{st} Revolution & 3\textsuperscript{rd} Revolution & 1\textsuperscript{st} Revolution & 3\textsuperscript{rd} Revolution \\
    \hline
    3 & 2.44\% & 6.74\% & 3.05\% & 10.4\% \\
    5 & 1.52\% & 6.65\% & 3.88\% & 11.0\% \\
    7 & 1.18\% & 2.34\% & 5.80\% & 7.11\% \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is not yet the most beautiful way of how to typeset this particular table, so keep on asking questions and looking for inspirations on this side! Consider for example using the [`booktabs` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/booktabs).

Comment: thank you for this. I will look into booktabs for my future writing.

Comment: Instead of `$1^{\textrm{st}}$ Revolution`, I'd write `1\textsuperscript{st} Revolution`. Better not to mix TeX's text and math idioms unnecessarily...

Comment: @Mico: Good point, updated the question. I usually don't use superscripts in text mode, so the macro didn't catch my mind when writing up the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following code should get you going.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l cccc }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Re=110$} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Re=1400$} \\
\emph{AR} & 1\textsuperscript{st} Revolution & 3\textsuperscript{rd} Revolution
          & 1\textsuperscript{st} Revolution & 3\textsuperscript{rd} Revolution \\
\midrule
3         & 2.44\% & 6.74\% & 3.05\% & 10.4\% \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \ldots \\ % just to demonstrate power/flexibility of \multicolumn
\multicolumn{1}{r}{7} & \ldots \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

`\multicolumn` takes three arguments: (1) the number of columns to be spanned, (2) the column type to be applied, and (3) what's to be typeset. The most common use of `\multicolumn` is, almost certainly, the placement of material that has to span two or more columns in a table header. However, `\multicolumn` can also be used to override the default column type for a single cell, as in done with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{5}` and `\multicolumn{1}{r}{7}` in the code above.

Comment: (+1) Very ingenious trick for the first column!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{\,}*{6}{c}@{\,}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Re=110$} & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$Re=1400$} \\%
 \arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro} \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l){2-3}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{5-6} \arrayrulecolor{black}
   $AR$ & \makecell{1\textsuperscript{st} Revolution \\ (\%)}&\makecell{3\textsuperscript{rd} Revolution \\ (\%)} & & \makecell{1\textsuperscript{st} Revolution \\ (\%)}& \makecell{3\textsuperscript{rd} Revolution \\ (\%)} \\
\midrule
    3 & 2.44 & 6.74 & \cellcolor{Gainsboro} & 3.05 & 10.4 \\
    5 & 1.52 & 6.65 & \cellcolor{Gainsboro} & 3.88 & 11.0 \\
    7 & 1.18 & 2.34 & \cellcolor{Gainsboro} & 5.80 & 7.11 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to replace the gray box with just a line?

Comment: You can replace each `cellcolor{Gainsboro}` with ` \multicolumn{1}{c}{\vrule width 0.8pt}. You can choose the colour of the line.

Comment: Ok I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Here is another attempt to answer the question. Though the table is made in entirely different context, the form remains the same. Hope it serves the purpose:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
     $Sl. No.$ & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$M_{bc}$} &  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$\Delta E$} &  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$NN'$}\\\cline{2-7}
    & $CBall$ & $Gauss$ & $CBall$ & $Gauss$ & $Bif. Gauss$ & $Gauss$ \\
     \hline\hline
     1 & $\mu$ & & & & & \\
     2 & & $\mu$ & & & &  \\
     3 & & & $\mu$ & & & \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image: The above code produces the following output]

Comment: Please don't use mathmode for italic text. `$Gauss$` is just *G·a·u·s²*, i.e. the product of variables. Use `\textit{Gauss}` instead (note the different spacing between the letters if you try it out)